# datetime picker in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing C# application and would like to allow user to enter the time as well as date in datetimepicker.Please let me know how to acheive this

Comment: What have you tried?  How did it not work as you expected?  Post the code that you've written so far.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET or other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instruct the DateTimePicker control to use a custom format, and provide a format that includes time elements:

```
this.dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy hh:mm";
this.dateTimePicker1.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

You can do this in the designer as well.